# OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server Refresh Token

Tags: oauth, owin

I run this sample application:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Downloaded from:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-OAuth-20-Authorization-ba2b8783

In the AuthorizationServer project Startup.Auth.cs file, I added

```
AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
```

inside

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
```

So that the token will expire after 1 minute.

After 1 minute and the token expired, I try to refresh the token, it gives me the error

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

My questions is:

Is it possible to refresh the token if the token expire? Or how about automatically refresh the expired token if the user tries to access Protected Resource?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You must return refresh token with access token and client will be able to get new access token using refresh token. For more information you can see this sample [link](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/
)

Answer (score 2):

By default, OWIN rejects refresh token if related authentication token expired already. Here is example, how you can override this behavior:

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            var ticket = LoadAuthenticationTicketFromDatabase();
            context.DeserializeTicket(ticket);
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the refresh token thus? Is not it supposed to give the possibility for the client to retrieve a new access token without having to login again? Forgive me, but your answer is quite confusing to me.